# ¿Cómo puedo bordear hacía dentro en css?

Tags: css

Cómo puedo bordear en CSS un div para que me quedé de la siguiente manera: [image: este es el resultado esperado]

Comment: ya intentaste el border radius, en valor negativo?

Comment: Hola... No funciona con valores negativos

Comment: Esto se puede conseguir de muchas maneras, ¿qué has intentado hacer y con qué problemas te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour], y luego edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar algo como esto, luego juegas con los números de alto y border radius para modificarlo un poco mas.

```css
.blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background: #00a8e5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blue:before {  
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: -80px;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 125px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='blue'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo usando una imagen de fondo radial.

```css
.fondo{
width: 480px;
 height: 100px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 240px 330px, white 300px, blue 0px);
}
```

```html
   <div class="fondo">

</div>
```